# Does the operand in a convolution have a particular name?

Tags: terminology, convolution

In a convolution:

$$(f*g*h)(t) = \int f(x)g(y)h(z) \delta(t-x-y-z) dxdydz$$

do the operands $f,g,h$ have a specific name, besides the general "operand"?

Comment: What are you looking for, something like "convolvand"? "convoluted"?

Comment: @Chappers Yes, something like that, if it is accepted terminology. Otherwise, if there if you know that there is no specific word for it in common use, you should state that in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am aware of no such word in standard usage. On the other hand, you have the verb *to convolve* [functions], so you would probably be understood, were you to coin *convolvand* or *convolutand* (although surely only one of these is a legitimate extrapolation). And you can call the functions *convolved* or *convoluted*: having been subject to convolution (the former probably being preferred).

Even *operand* is not often used. Normally you'd see something like *input* or *argument*. This case is a bit tricky, as technically convolution is a binary operation from integrable functions to integrable functions (no doubt with an associated semigroup structure on it), so the argument of $(f * g)$ could be $f$ or $g$, or the variable that $(f * g)$ is applied to as a function.